# How to validate that a user owns the requested resource through Rails API when using devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building an API-only (for now) Rails app to serve as the back end for an Android app I'm building. I was previously using Firebase but wanted to do more processing on application data and I didn't want to bloat the mobile client with all the logic, so I am moving away from Firebase's real-time database and backing the application data using Rails. I was also using Firebase's authentication which is very straightforward. But it seems less complex for the overall system to keep all of this functionality in one place, so I'd like to perform auth and user management in the Rails app as well.

I have installed `devise_token_auth` (seen [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)) and finished the basic configuration. The `/auth` route works correctly if params are provided and creates a user. `sign_in` and `sign_out` both successfully create sessions and return some header information. The important parts returned are `client`, `access-token`, and `uid`, which I need to use in future calls to the API. I believe these are invalidated and replaced with each subsequent call. At this part of the flow is where I'm not sure how to proceed. I don't understand how the data in these headers is associated with the user who signed in and how I can validate that they own a resource they request. To summarize the question another way:

**How can I sign a user into the API and then validate which user is making subsequent API calls?**

My Android app is a task manager, so I need to be able to validate for example that if `user 1` requests `task 3`, that they own that resource. I'm also unsure how to direct index calls using the API. That is, when the index endpoint is hit (`/tasks`), how can I identify from the data in the API headers which user's tasks I should retrieve.

I haven't been able to find any solid tutorials or samples using `devise_token_auth` so I'm having trouble stitching together the interaction between the pieces I have now. I know this is a meaty question - thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I [...] validate which user is making subsequent API calls?

With the `current_user` method. This is a [built-in feature](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#methods) to the `devise_token_auth` gem.

> I need to be able to validate for example that if user 1 requests task 3, that they own that resource

There are many different approaches you could take. You *could* just write some custom logic in each controller action, using the `current_user` method (and return `403 forbidden` if necessary).

Or, you could use a popular "framework" solution for this such as [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [`Pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). I, and probably most of the modern community, would recommend `Pundit`.

I *highly* advise you to read that library's README, as it's extremely helpful. But for the example above, you could write something like this:

```
class TasksController
  def show
    task = Task.find(params[:id])
    authorize(task) # !!!
    render task
  end
end

# app/policies/task_policy.rb
class TaskPolicy
  def show?
    record.user == user
  end
end
```

(Note that by default, the "`user`" in Pundit policies calls the method: `current_user`. This is all explained in the project's README.)

> when the index endpoint is hit (`/tasks`), how can I identify from the data in the API headers which user's tasks I should retrieve

Again, this is all handled as part of `Pundit`'s standard features. You just need to define a `TaskPolicy::Scope` and call `policy_scope(Task)` in the controller - as explained [here](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes).

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment, it was an issue with something else in the ApplicationController. After setting this up, I get `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError`. I hit the `sign_in` endpoint and receive the user back with id 2. Then I call for a task that belongs to user with id 2, but receive the above error. What have I done wrong?

Comment: In trying to troubleshoot this, I've isolated down to `current_user` being unavailable in my policy file. I've done some logging in the controller upstream to verify that it works there, so for some reason it's only unavailable downstream.

Comment: Why are you writing `current_user` inside the policy class? Read my answer again, and re-read the pundit readme: You just need to use `user`.

Comment: Because `user` was `nil` so I was experimenting with removing the layer of abstraction as part of debugging. Because I'm new to `devise_token_auth` and working with an API only application, it took me a while to debug. But I realized the issue was with the headers in my request. tl;dr, `current_user` (and therefore `user`) was `nil` because the API call was determined as invalid because I hadn't realized the access-token was invalid. Ensuring to pass up-to-date header information works. Thanks a ton for the detailed answer, really helped me out!

Comment: @justinraczak Regarding the "user is nil" issue: Note that the `devise_token_auth` gem also provides a [`before_action :authenticate_user!`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#methods) method that you should call on all controller actions that require a signed in user. This will prevent subtle `nil` issues like that, and also return the correct `401` (i.e. not `403` or `404`) response code for unauthorized user access.